# Can 'iterator' type just subclass 'const_iterator'?

Tags: c++, casting, iterator, containers

After [another question about iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844339/c-iterator-and-const-iterator-problem-for-own-container-class) I'm having some doubts about custom containers.  In my container, `iterator` is a subclass of `const_iterator`, so that I get conversion from non-const to const "for free".  But is this allowed or are there any drawbacks or non-working scenarios for such a setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. This is how VC10's implementation of the iterators for `vector` are structured, for example. See `_Vector_iterator` and `_Vector_const_iterator` in `<vector>`.

By the way, writing iterators is hard. It's worth your time to learn and use the boost::iterator library.

Comment: I know, but in my case it's a small library and I don't want it to depend on anything, including Boost parts.

Comment: It's already good that some implementation of STL works like that.  Do you happen to know a clause in the standard that describes iterators and requirements in general?

Comment: 24.2 of the FCD (n3035.pdf) describes iterators and their requirements

Comment: Thanks.  Let's wait if more opinions appear.

Answer (score 4):

Subclassing seems strange to me here, but there is effectively an issue.

Even if you don't want to depend on Boost parts, check the Boost.Iterator library, and more especially the `iterator_facade` and `iterator_adaptor` bits.

There is a full-blown example of how to write an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` for your class without duplicating too much. Their idea is to write a template `iterator_base` class which you can then use for const and non-const types in the line of:

```
template <class Value> class iterator_base;

typedef iterator_base<T> iterator;
typedef iterator_base<const T> const_iterator;
```

The issue with subclassing is that you should then provide a virtual destructor and you're exposed to slicing (when building a `const_iterator` from an `iterator`)

So, unlike others here, I don't find it "fine".

Comment: "You should then provide a virtual destructor" — but my destructors don't do anything anyway.  Even if they did, `iterator` type would probably just inherit `const_iterator` destructor, without doing anything extra.  "you're exposed to slicing" — can you please elaborate, I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: An example of slicing, `iterator it; const_iterator cit = static_cast<const_iterator>( it );`. Here, when you are assigning the typecasted `it` to `cit`, whatever extra variables you have added to `it` is **not** copied into `cit`. But I think this is ok since we can never downcast to `iterator` again.

Answer (score -1):

Think about a case which will require you to modify the iterator's members.

Comment: And?  I guess you need to elaborate.