# Increment operator/ iterator implementation

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list, post-increment

I am trying to figure out a couple of things here:

1. How do I write an increment operator for a node class that has a pointer to the next node?
2. How do I implement iterators for a class like below?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   using namespace std;

   template <typename T>
   class Node {
   public:
       Node(int i=0):val(i) {}
       Node*& operator++(int i=0) {return next;};

       T val;
       Node *next;
   };

   //================================================
   int main() {

       Node<int> *head, *tmp1, *tmp2;

       tmp1 = new Node<int>(0); 
       head = tmp1;

       for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) {

           tmp2 = new Node<int>(i);
           tmp1->next = tmp2;
           tmp1 = tmp2;
       }

       while (head != NULL) {

           cout << head->val << " '";
           head = head->operator++(0);    //How do I make it work with ++head;?
       }
   }
   ```

This is not a good example for demonstrating operator overloading or iterators.

Comment: You cant. head is a pointer and ++ operator is builtin/defined for pointers. If head was an object or reference to an object then you could do it.

Comment: hmm..okay. Do you know of any links to implementating iterators? Thanks you

Comment: You could look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators

Comment: @Fred; as you suggested deriving STL iterators I was looking at the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/. So if I want to read and write, should I just use random_access_iterator_tag ? or do you recommend any others?

Comment: I would recommend starting from [boost::iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html), which helps provide some of the infrastructure that proper iterators need.  It even has a tutorial that goes along with it.

Comment: @blueskin: In order to be a random access iterator, your iterator would have to implement `operator+(int)` and `operator-(int)` as well as `operator++()` and `operator--()`. I think what you would have here for a singly-linked list is a forward iterator.

Comment: @ephemient: hmm... thats a good place to start understanding a better iterator design but for my application I am looking at just using C++ and STL. Thanks ephemient

Comment: @Fred: exactly thats what I was looking at.. I was also looking at qlist.h to understand how they separated interface from implementation. Thanks Fred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't implement `operator++` for the Node class; you implement it for the iterator. The iterator class should be a separate class.

And please, don't spoil your template by making assumptions (since `val` is a `T`, your constructor should accept a `T`, not an `int`). Also, do not ignore the `int` parameter to operator++ like that: it is a dummy used to distinguish the pre-increment implementation from the post-increment implementation.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T val;
    Node *next;

    Node(const T& t = T()) : val(t) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct node_iter {
    Node<T>* current;
    node_iter(Node<T>* current): current(current) {}

    const node_iter& operator++() { current = current->next; return *this; }
    node_iter operator++(int) {
        node_iter result = *this; ++(*this); return result;
    }
    T& operator*() { return current->val; }
};

int main() {
    // We make an array of nodes, and link them together - no point in
    // dynamic allocation for such a simple example.
    Node<int> nodes[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        nodes[i] = Node<int>(i);
        nodes[i].next = (i == 9) ? nodes + i + 1 : 0;
    }

    // we supply a pointer to the first element of the array
    node_iter<int> test(nodes);
    // and then iterate:
    while (test.current) {
        cout << *test++ << " ";
    }
    // Exercise: try linking the nodes in reverse order. Therefore, we create 
    // 'test' with a pointer to the last element of the array, rather than 
    // the first. However, we will not need to change the while loop, because
    // of how the operator overload works.

    // Exercise: try writing that last while loop as a for loop. Do not use
    // any information about the number of nodes.
}
```

This is still a long, long way off from providing proper data encapsulation, memory management etc. Making a proper linked list class is **not** easy. That's why the standard library provides one. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I realized that after posting this. I was actually trying to understand to how to implement iterators, its a bad example that I gave. I think QList is well implemented than STL list. I will try to implement something like that. Thanks Karl

Comment: http://en.literateprograms.org/Singly_linked_list_%28C_Plus_Plus%29 is more helpful

Comment: Why does operator++() return a const reference and operator++(int) return a value?

Comment: @AlexanderDuchene I don't know for sure, but I think it's because in post-increment, you have to return the value that existed prior to incrementing, whereas pre-increment returns a const reference to the iterator because it's used solely for advancing the iterator. Notice that post-increment also uses pre-increment to advance the iterator.