# Linked list const iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, const-iterator

I have implemented a doubly-linked list, and created an iterator which extends `std::iterator`. I'm now trying to create a `const` version.

I tried:

```
typename typedef list_iterator<T_>        iterator;
typename typedef list_iterator<T_> const  const_iterator;
```

If I do this though, I get this error:

```
error C2678: binary '--' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const    list_iterator<T_>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Here is my `operator--`:

```
list_iterator& operator -- ()
{
    _current = _current->_previous;
    return *this;
}

list_iterator operator--(int) // postfix
{
    list_iterator hold = *this;
    --*this;
    return list_iterator( hold );
}
```

If I put

```
list_iterator operator--() const
```

... I'm not able to modify the value of `_current`

How do I make my iterator now work like a `const_iterator` so that from my linked list I can call get the const version of `begin()` and `end()`, as well as `cbegin()` and `cend()`?

Comment: try declaring _current mutable

Comment: a `const_iterator` and a `const iterator` are _VERY_ different things.  They actually need to be two different types, sorry.  It's the difference between "a constant pointer to data", and "a pointer to constant data"

Comment: So I need to make a whole new iterator class then?

Answer (score 2):

Right.  The problem is your declaration of your const_iterator typedef.  (See [How to correctly implement custom iterators and const_iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators) )

Instead of

```
typename typedef list_iterator<T_> const  const_iterator;
```

you want

```
typename typedef list_iterator<const  T_> const_iterator;
```