# Can I iterate over class members as though they were an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have a class akin to the following:

```
struct Potato {
    Eigen::Vector3d position;
    double weight, size;
    string name;
};
```

and a collection of `Potato`s

```
std::vector<Potato> potato_farm = {potato1, potato2, ...};
```

This is pretty clearly an array-of-structures (AoS) layout because, let's say for most purposes, it makes sense to have all of a `Potato`'s data lumped together. However, I might like to do a calculation of the most common name where a structure-of-arrays (SoA) design makes things agnostic to the type of thing with a name (an array of people all with names, an array of places, all with names, etc.) Does C++ have any tools or tricks that makes an AoS layout *look* like a SoA to do something like this, or is there a better design that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: how would it make it any easier? or how is calculating the mean not easy now? Just iterate over your `potato_farm`, access the weight, calc the mean, done. Of course if you mean more memory efficient then it might have a advantage to have a structure of arrays, but I dont get the point of different "looks" because there is little difference in the code to get eg the mean weight

Comment: @tobi303 It's much more natural to interface with STL algorithms with a structure of arrays (each of the arrays would have `begin` and `end` methods that can feed an e.g. `std::accumulate` natively without having to write a whole bunch of lambda functions to dig out the relevant member variables).

Comment: @ConnorGlosser You only have to write a single lambda for `std::accumulate` though, not a lot. It's not "easier" with your structures of arrays IMO.

Comment: @ConnorGlosser yeah I was thinking about it, you would have to write some boilerplate to make `std::accumulate` access the members

Comment: Your `potato_farm` could provide an `begin` and `end` iterator for each member. That iterator simply wraps the vector iterator but returns the appropriate member when dereferenced. Then you would save the lambdas

Comment: @Rakete1111 A better example might be some code that processes a collection of `name`s, be they for potatoes, people, places, etc. In that case it'd be really easy to pull out the `std::vector<std::string>` from any SoA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no language tool to generically change a struct into SoA. This is actually one of big obstacles when you try to bring SIMD programming into higher level.

You will need to create a SoA manually. However, you can help yourself by creating a reference to SoA objects acting as if it was a regular Potato.

```
struct Potato {
    float position;
    double weight, size;
    std::string name;
};
struct PotatoSoARef {
    float& position;
    double& weight;
    double& size;
    std::string& name;
};
class PotatoSoA {
private:
    float* position;
    double* weight;
    double* size;
    std::string* name;
public:
    PotatoSoA(std::size_t size) { /* allocate the SoA */ }
    PotatoSoARef operator[](std::size_t idx) {
        return PotatoSoARef{position[idx], weight[idx], size[idx], name[idx]};
    }
};
```

This way, regardless if you have an AoS or SoA of Potatos, you can access its fields as `arr[idx].position` etc. (both as r- and l-value). The compiler is likely to optimize the proxy away.

You might want to add other constructors and accessors as well.

You might also be interested in implementing a regular AoS with an `operator[]` returning a `PotatoSoARef` if you want functions to have a uniform interface for both AoS and SoA access patterns.

---

If you are willing to depart from C++ though, you might be interested in language extensions such as [Sierra](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2568062)

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambdas to access particular member in algos that work over range:

```
double mean = std::accumulate( potato_farm.begin(), potato_farm.end(), 0.0, []( double val, const Potato &p ) { return val + p.weight; } ) / potato_farm.size();
```

if that is not enough you cannot make it look like array of data as that requires objects to be in continuous memory, but you can make it like a container. So you can implement custom iterators (for example random access iterator of `type == double` which iterates over weight member). How to implement custom iterators is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators). You can probably even make that generic, but it is not clear if that would worse the effort as it is not very simple to implement properly.

Answer (score 0):

As Slava has said you aren't going to get SoA-like access out of AoS data without writing your own iterators, and I would think *really* hard about whether the use of STL algorithms is that important before doing that, especially if this isn't meant to be a generic solution. The primary benefit of SoA data is cache performance anyway, not the particular syntax of whatever containers you're using, and nothing besides *actual SoA data* is going to get you that.

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (not in C++17 :-/ ), you may use Projection or transformation view:

```
ranges::accumulate(potato_farm, 0., ranges::v3::plus{}, &Potato::weight);
```

or

```
auto weightsView = potato_farm | ranges::view::transform([](auto& p) { return p.weight; });
ranges::accumulate(weightsView, 0.);
```