# Is it possible to reuse usual iterator to build const iterator?

Tags: c++, c++14, code-reuse, const-iterator

### Research

I found [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582733/4593721). I'd like to know if the solution is still effective or if there is a new, more effective way to do it.

### Background

Lets suppose I have an iterator like below (specifics don't really matter, only that it is huge):

```
    class inorder_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, token>
    {
        friend syntax_tree;

        node* current_node;
        std::stack<node*> prev_nodes;
        //std::stack<node*> visited_nodes;
        std::map<node*, bool> visited;
    public:
        inorder_iterator();

        inorder_iterator& operator++();
        inorder_iterator operator++(int);

        token& operator*();
        const token& operator*() const;

        token* operator->();
        const token* operator->() const;

        friend bool operator==(const inorder_iterator lhs, const inorder_iterator rhs);
        friend bool operator!=(const inorder_iterator lhs, const inorder_iterator rhs);

    private:
        inorder_iterator(node* current);
        node* find_leftmost_node(node* from);
    };
```

### Problem

Implementations of the member function declarations are of reasonable size, but I would like to reuse the current iterator to reduce code duplication.

### Idea

First idea that came to mind is to templatize on `node` type, so I could pass `const node` to make it const iterator, but it just sounds fishy

```
template <typename Node>
//replace every occurrence of node with Node
// and use decltype(node.tk) instead of token everywhere
```

Also I'm not sure if this use of `const` is one of those "const belongs to implementation specifics" case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A template is probably the only way to avoid code duplication. But I wouldn't leave the type parameter open. I'd simply use a boolean parameter that is fed to a `std::conditional` in order to determine the type:

```
template<bool IsConst> class iter_impl {
  using value_type = std::conditional_t<IsConst, Node const, Node>;
};
```

The two iterator types of the container can then be either a couple of aliases, or if you want truly distinct types, a couple of classes that inherit from the template. Like so:

```
struct const_iterator : iter_impl<true> {};
struct iterator : iter_impl<false> {};
```

The benefit of using two new classes, is that you can define a converting constructor for `const_iterator` that allows it to be build from the non const iterator. This is akin to the standard library's behavior.

> Also I'm not sure if this use of const is one of those "const belongs to implementation specifics" case.

The fact you use a `const Node` is indeed an implementation detail. But so long as it gives you the documented type behavior (an iterator to a const member of the container) I wouldn't stress too much over this.

Comment: Thanks for good answer. By the way, you would be great contributor on CodeReview too!

Comment: @Incomputable - Thanks :) I dipped my toe in the water there recently. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely define class template `template< typename value_type > iterator` parametrized by value type (`const` or non-`const`) with conversion operator to `const` version (i.e. `operator interator< value_type const > () const`):

```
template< typename type >
struct node
        : node_base
{

    union { type value; };

    node() noexcept { ; }

    node(node const &) = delete;
    node(node &&) = delete;
    void operator = (node const &) = delete;
    void operator = (node &&) = delete;

    ~node() { ; }

    type * pointer() noexcept { return &value; }

};

template< typename type >
struct tree_iterator
{

    using value_type = type;
    using reference = type &;
    using pointer = type *;

    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    using node_type = node< value_type >;
    using node_pointer = node_type *;

    base_pointer p = nullptr;

    pointer operator -> () const noexcept { return node_pointer(p)->pointer(); }
    reference operator * () const noexcept { return *operator -> (); }

    tree_iterator & operator ++ () noexcept { p = increment(p); return *this; }
    tree_iterator operator ++ (int) noexcept { return {std::exchange(p, increment(p))}; }

    tree_iterator & operator -- () noexcept { p = decrement(p); return *this; }
    tree_iterator operator -- (int) noexcept { return {std::exchange(p, decrement(p))}; }

    bool operator == (tree_iterator const & it) const noexcept { return p == it.p; }
    bool operator != (tree_iterator const & it) const noexcept { return !operator == (it); }

    operator tree_iterator< type const > () const { return {p}; }

};
```

In `using const_iterator = iterator< value_type const >;` the latter became no-op and can be called only intentionally (i.e. using syntax `it.template operator iterator< value_type const > ()`).

The code is given from [here](https://github.com/tomilov/sweepline/blob/master/rb_tree.hpp) - rewrite of *libstdc++*'s red-black tree.

Comment: Thanks for another solution, but I believe StoryTeller's solution fits better to me for now.