# How to properly define inherited iterator template?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have stumbled upon somehow stupid problem, yet I have not found any answear or even question about it. 
I am implementing custom transforming input iterator, and want to do something like that:

```
template<class T>
class my_it : 
public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T, ??? should I put anything here ??? > {
    ...
    my_proxy_with_implemented_arrow<T> operator->();
    T operator*();
    ...
};
```

As the type name says - proxy has implemented `operator->` to get pointer behaviour.
And so my question is, should I define `pointer` template argument in inherited `std::iterator` to `my_proxy_with_implemented_arrow<T>` and `reference` to `T` or should I keep the default values and don't care about return values?

In other words - do the types given in inherited `std::iterator` should be the same as the types returned by the iterator operators?

Comment: Just follow [the example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). Also note the "deprecated in C++17", so arguably you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801650/5945883

Comment: @nwp So what should I use? What is the alternative? And will it work with previous standards?

Comment: The alternative is to drop the inheritance and implement all the [requirements for your iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) by hand, including the linked ones.

Comment: @nwp Fine, but will iterator_traits work properly if I don't define, for example, iterator tag?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by iterator tag. As it says in the above mentioned documentation you need to satisfy [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) which means, among other things, that `std::iterator_traits<my_it>` must have a member typedef `iterator_category` and so on. If you follow all the requirements it will work properly. All the requirements include all the tags, typedefs and operators, so it probably includes your iterator tag.