# How to use `std::lower_bound` with this custom-made container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, search, iterator

I would like a wrapper for a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` object. Here are a few basic methods implemented under `Wrapper`

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& data;
    int totalSize;
    std::vector<int> indicesMap;

public:
    Wrapper(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& input):data(input)
    {
        totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++)
        {
            totalSize += data[i].size();
            indicesMap.push_back(totalSize);
        }
    }

    T operator[](int index)
    {
        int whichVector = std::upper_bound(
            indicesMap.begin(),
            indicesMap.end(),
            index
        ) - indicesMap.begin();

        int i = whichVector == 0 ? index : index - indicesMap[whichVector-1];

        return data[whichVector][i];
    }

    int size()
    {
        return totalSize;
    }
};
```

Here is a simple test

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> x;
    std::vector<int> x1 = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> x2 = {10,20,30};
    std::vector<int> x3 = {100,200,300};
    x.push_back(x1);
    x.push_back(x2);
    x.push_back(x3);

    Wrapper<int> w(x);
    std::cout << w[4] << "\n"; // prints 20 as expected

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to use `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` on the object `Wrapper`. I don't really understand how to make iterators to custom-made objects though and fail to implement that and even then, I am not quite sure it is feasible to just give the being and end iterators to `lower_bound`.

Can you help me to implement `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` for the object `Wrapper`?

My goal would be to be able to do

```
std::lower_bound(w.begin(), w.end(), object);
```

Comment: What on earth is this Wrapper trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a function that is aimed to work on `std::vector<T>` and on `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. The goal of the wrapper is to allow to template this function and use the STL function `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and the methods `erase`, `insert` as well as the `operator[]` without having to deal with the underlying complication of the data structure. Does it sound like a very bad idea? @RichardHodges

Comment: @Slava They are STL algorithms to perform binary search (in sorted arrays) . The functions take ForwardIt as input and output ForwardIt. Why do you think I misunderstand how they work? My goal is to run something like `std::lower_bound(w.begin(), w.end(), object);`, where `w` is the `Wrapper`. Does it make sense?

Comment: I take it back, I misread your existing usage of `upper_bound`

Comment: No worries. As both you and Richard get a hard time with my question, I suspect it is my fault. Is the question clearly defined now?

Comment: That looks a bit like a `std::deque`. Are you sure `srd::deque` won't satisfy your needs? Anyway, doing a standard binary search on your data structure will not be optimal; you'd do better to first binary search for the vector holding the value, and then binary search that vector for the value.

Comment: No, I don't think it would, although I understand your suggestion. The point of the wrapper is that `data` is a reference to the original data. I did not want to have to copy the input vector over but just to wrap it for a number of operations.

Comment: @remi: I was referring to the original "vector of vector s" object, which looks to me something like a `std::deque`. The possible difference is that the individual vectors in the `std::deque` are all the same size, which simplifies some operations; in particular, indexing is O(1) rather than O(log N). But I understand that it might not help you; it was just a thought. The advantage is that `std::deque` already has iterators. I'd suggest looking at an implementation of that to see how it's done, but I've yet to find a standard library implementation optimized for ease of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create and implement iterators for your wrapper that satisfy concept [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator). Details on how to do that can be found in answers to this subject [How to correctly implement custom iterators and const_iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators). Then provide methods of your wrapper that return first and behind the past iterator (usually they called `begin()` and `end()` and they better be but you can call them whatever way you want).

Iterator can be implemented as `std::pair<size_t,size_t>` with positions in `data` plus reference to `data` itself with proper implementation of `operator++`.

Optionally for optimization you may want to make your iterator to satisfy [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) concept and `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` could be more efficient (depends on how you implement random access of course).