# C++14 Make custom iterator, that will go by 2 and returns modified data

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I have class `Range` which holds a interval like `<2,10>` or `<-50,900>`
and than I have `RangeList` and I want to have `vector<long long>` which represents multiple ranges. I don't need to have `vector<Range>` for some purpose.

But i want to make iterator that will go through `ranges` and it will retrun Range. Is it possible to define custom iterator that will work like that?

```
   class Range {
        long long lo;
        long long hi;
    }

    class RangeList {
    vector<long long> ranges;

    }
```

example

```
ranges={1, 50, 200, 700, 900, 1000};
```

so iterator will go through and it would return

first iteration

```
Range <1,50>
```

secondi teration

```
Range <200,700>
```

third teration

```
Range <900,100>
```

**Thanks for any advice**

Comment: Yes it's possible ;-)

Comment: How about: `boost::tranform_iterator` [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html)?

Comment: It is possible but perhaps counterproductive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators

Comment: *Why* don't you want a `vector<Range>`? I'd be tempted to have `using Ranges = std::vector<Range>;`, and sidestep `RangeList`

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I will do it as you sa in vector<Range>, I am not allowed to use boost, but you are right :) thanks guys

Comment: @StykPohlavsson: The Boost license is about as permissive as StackOverflow. If you're working in an environment that bans all outside code, you probably shouldn't be asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i'd be a little more specific as I don't like to infer pairs from a sequential list of values (what happens if there's an odd number of values?)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class Integer>
struct InclusiveRangeIter
{
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = Integer;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using difference_type = Integer;

    constexpr InclusiveRangeIter(Integer current)
    : value_(current)
    {}

    constexpr bool operator==(InclusiveRangeIter const& other) const { return value_ == other.value_; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(InclusiveRangeIter const& other) const { return value_ != other.value_; }
    value_type operator*() const { return value_; }
    auto operator++() -> InclusiveRangeIter& { ++value_; return *this; }
    auto operator++(int) -> InclusiveRangeIter { auto copy = *this; ++value_; return copy; }


    Integer value_;
};

struct InclusiveRange 
{
    long long lo;
    long long hi;

    auto begin() const { return InclusiveRangeIter(lo); }
    auto end() const { return InclusiveRangeIter(hi + 1); }
};

int main()
{
    auto ranges = std::vector<InclusiveRange>
    {
        {1, 50}, {200, 700}, {900, 1000}
    };

    for (auto&& ir : ranges)
    {
        auto sep = false;
        for (auto&& v : ir)
        {
            if (sep) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << v;
            sep = true;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2804de3d85ba4f0b