# Multi-dimensional datasets in C++: cleanest approach to go from a std::vector of 2D data, to a 2D grid of std::vectors?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++14, std, stdvector

**Context:**
I've been processing scientific satellite images, currently keeping the individual end results at each timestamp as `cv::Mat_<double>`, which can for instance be stored in a std::container of images, such as a `std::vector<cv::Mat_<double>>`.

**The issue:**
I would now like to study the physical properties of each individual pixel over time. For that, it would be far preferable if I could look at the data along the time dimension and work with a 2D table of vectors instead. In other words: to have a `std::vector<double>` associated to each pixel on the 2D grid that is common to all images.

A reason for that is that the type of calculations (computing percentiles, curve fitting, etc) will rely on `std::algorithms` and libraries which expect to be fed with `std::vectors` and the like. For a given pixel the data is definitely not contiguous in memory along the time dimension though.

**Can/Should I really avoid copying the data in such a case?** If yes, what would be the best approach, then? By best I mean efficient yet as 'clean'/'clear' as possible.

I thought of `std::reference_wrapper` to store the addresses in a `std::vector`; it's simple and works but each entry takes as much memory as if I had simply duplicated the data in a `std::vector<double>`. Each data point is just a double after all.

NB:
I've stumbled upon Boost MultiArray, but I'd like to avoid having to add a Boost dependency.

Many thanks in advance for your time/input.

Comment: <algorithm> targets iterators, not containers. Have you considered writing custom iterators for the original data?

Comment: Why are you even trying to avoid a copy? A copy is as fast as it gets for your requirements.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thank you very much for the idea. No, and I have actually never done that, so I'm not sure how hard it is; I'll definitely have a look. It might be a bit premature now, but interesting in the longer run.

Comment: @Ext3h I simply always try to question extra copies. But in this specific case I just couldn't find an alternative satisfactory approach. Hence this sanity check, in case I missed an extremely obvious solution. Thank you for your comment. I guess I've been playing a bit too much with python and got used to getting numpy arrays out of essentially everything.

Comment: The iterator requirements differs between algorithms but begin(), end() and operator ++ and operator * should be relatively straightforward. Should you be interested in  examples you can find a related discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582608/451600 . Almost all algorithms don't require a complete iterator.

Comment: For future reference and anyone who might also be interested: I've since learned that in the literature this discussion is actually called "AoS vs SoA" (Array of Structure vs Structure of Array), as seen on these slides about the Eigen library: http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/eigen/eigen_CGLibs_Giugno_Pisa_2013.pdf#page=94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) (or it's precursors, [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1transform__view.html) and [boost range adaptors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html)), with function objects to lookup each pixel

```
[x, y](cv::Mat_<double> & mat) -> double & { return mat[y][x]; }
```

However you should definitely profile if that is worthwhile vs copying, as I expect the cache locality to be horrible.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I had never looked into Ranges and views in C++20, as I'm using older compilers. I actually did not know that this was called locality either, but it indeed feels like it's going to be pretty bad. 

I think I'll just accept dealing with copies now, especially since it's obviously going to be a much simpler approach.

Out of curiosity, I've had a quick look at numpy, where (even more) extreme/arbitrary slicing is frequent (as in pandas and xarray), and they actually simply return a copy in some cases.