# implementing a cpp const iterator crashes and burns

Tags: c++, iterator

Many posts about const iterators ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582608/how-to-correctly-implement-custom-iterators-and-const-iterators)), but none in the context of loops like:

```
for (const auto it: container) { ... }
```

When I started implementing, I was *encouraged* by the compiler's *complaints* about missing `begin` and `end`, hoping such complaints can *guide me to fill in the missing pieces*. I was wrong. The following code compiles fine though it surely lacks the equivalent of both `operator++` and `operator!=`:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T> class List { public:
    const T *head;
    const List<T> *tail;
    List(const T *h, const List<T> *t):head(h),tail(t){}
    const T *operator*() const { return head; } };

template<class T> const List<T> *begin(const List<T> *l) { return l; }
template<class T> const List<T> *end  (const List<T> *l) { return nullptr; }

class Person { public: int age; Person(int a):age(a){} };
typedef List<Person> Persons;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Person *p1 = new Person(16);
    Person *p2 = new Person(27);
    Person *p3 = new Person(38);

    Persons *persons = new Persons(p1,
        new Persons(p2,
        new Persons(p3, nullptr)));

    for (const auto p: persons) { std::cout << (*p)->age << "\n"; }
    return 0; }
```

How come this code compiles?

Comment: there is no iterators here. and range for loop is just a shorthand syntax for a normal for-loop

Comment: `++` and `!=` are defined for all pointer types

Comment: It's not obvious to me why `persons`, a `Persons*` pointer, is being treated as a valid range expression. The only [case](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) that looks like it might be able to apply is treating it as an array type whose size isn't known.

Comment: It’s because begin() and end() functions were defined that accept List* as their argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not defined `++` and `!=`, but they are perfectly well-defined for your iterator type, `const List<T>*`, because is a pointer type. However, the default behavior of `++` does not do what you want, which would be to follow the `tail` pointer.

To imbue your iterator with special knowledge of how `++` should be implemented, you would want to use a separate, custom iterator class, rather than using a pointer.

I also made some other changes to your code:

- The `List` type is made iterable, not `List*`. That means the `begin` and `end` functions are not defined on pointers, but on the List object itself, and we iterate over `*persons` rather than `persons`.
- In `for (const auto p : *persons)`, `p` is a `Person`, not a pointer.

[godbolt.org link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEs6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEhqkAA6oCoRODB7evv5JKWkCIWGRLDFxXAl2mA7pQgRMxASZPn5cAZXVArX1BIUR0bHxtnUNTdmtQ929xaXxAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuTgoExJisB9gmGgCCBJgsiQb3B27bTAoKuwAql7vvn12IRO%2BwA7BZdokvFFaHhkCBrjddsj/gIQd9dgAqBDndAHKy3FGohgg4EEV6/dbYLF1Oj4xFEskQNAkgg/LEIUjE0l4E4Uv6YgizEA4pjoCAIea02gQIUmcHygAiDJRLPRWNQiViTCIxExEFm3LZ8ohZwISwYu1FePWEKViJVyIBXzVBAA%2BoRtbqwQSkUTVWi2WT%2BVTMf8lvt1ordgwvLRaIlTvTCSioTC4QiU/7dphVE84YQjR77sQdSRmYGgbzyYdKdgw7CToaQOHiBBG0Kffas/7XcWvSRzAA2XaagfEazWA1dnvZp0Rg7R5BLAC0l2lyb9c5RZotNIQvM32%2B7W/9UVQnlHWtLurAYEXFdZRc9N8HZhHqAIOOIhtdM9P267sQlrLsQux3ouo5frEAB0oFHnOJ7bn%2Bvzvle476r%2BlYmo6267EBlqYqBa5UtaCHZkhKL2raDo9n2L5lmBMTAKE05/jhs47pg5rAc%2BJaMbKB4KLM5Fgsqty4fR/Heq4bHYQqnHIgRfHjhAsbxomP6iSe1G%2Boizq7MosQKAIPqQtCsLwrsoRskwwCYPihnGQIEA2bsTDCnZmAQB5OGgtGumIgQACeWpYFQVZ8ocRnECZDB/DFcUKJuiJuSwTCsW59TAMgXLIAg9RYpi2UAG6Ghxp6JaZmKJFwkbRmEADuTmxS5XBDiJNE9lVhGJGY9UxpgzU9RAZigp1vpEj1WKJOsA1NS1cUQOsAAcE20ZVzkkjNW1fJBC09QoEC1aQuFEgdu3HQEZ0ohdrUksd6xcupCanLM70pT2/BgY%2BIJMF4RCQi2NW7eVCkASiJzoCAKCLMahyvJCMFeZGbiI%2BYZgmAArG48VmJjXWnpRSncXuGgpf5uEcPMtCcFjvB%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%2BYCy5HnRIptC782LqXEW71SASylvoTgcs5EK1DsrVWQs7GBw4GYYOCjEFl1FqQZesV0ggEkEAA)

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T> class List { public:
    const T *head;
    const List<T> *tail;
    List(const T *h, const List<T> *t):head(h),tail(t){}
    const T *operator*() const { return head; }

    class const_iterator {
        const List<T>* cur = nullptr;
    public:
        explicit const_iterator(const List<T>* list) : cur(list) {}
        const_iterator& operator++() {
            cur = cur->tail;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& other) const {
            return cur != other.cur;
        }
        const T& operator*() const {
            return *cur->head;
        }
    };

    const_iterator begin() const {
        return const_iterator(this);
    }

    const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator(nullptr);
    }
};

class Person { public: int age; Person(int a):age(a){} };
typedef List<Person> Persons;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Person *p1 = new Person(16);
    Person *p2 = new Person(27);
    Person *p3 = new Person(38);

    Persons *persons = new Persons(p1,
        new Persons(p2,
        new Persons(p3, nullptr)));

    for (const auto p: *persons) {
        std::cout << p.age << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```