# Understanding iterator class in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

Recently in class we were taught about the STL iterator to traverse through lists. In the example code given for a basic Iterator for a linked list I came across something that I couldn't make sense of.

We were given 2 Iterator classes, const_iterator and iterator. They were both sub-classes of the List class. iterator inherited from const_iterator. In the constructor of iterator I'm not sure why it was written like this;

iterator class:

```
class iterator:public const_iterator{ 
    friend sortedList
protected:
    iterator(Node* n):const_iterator(n){}
public:
    iterator(){ 
        n = nullptr;
    }
```

The const_iterator class:

```
    class const_iterator { 
    friend SortedList 
protected:
    Node* curr_;
    const_iterator(Node* n){ 
        curr_ = n; 
    }
public:
    const_iterator(){
        curr_ = nullptr;
    }
```

My question is why does iterator inherit from const_iterator and why is iterator's constructor initializing the const_iterator ctor and doing nothing to itself.

Side question; when accessing curr_ from iterator how would I refer to it? Would I just call curr_ or would I use this->curr_?

Comment: That is not Standard Library code. To understand it, we would need to see a lot more of whatever implementation you are asking about.

Comment: Anyway, the default-ctor in `iterator` looks broken.

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844466/can-iterator-type-just-subclass-const-iterator that may help you understand the rationale between inheriting from const_iterator. I personally don't like this way of doing it because IMO public inheritance should be used to convey a 'public' information (i.e model a is-a relationship for objects that will be used polymorphically) which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why does iterator inherit from const_iterator and why is iterator's constructor initializing the const_iterator ctor and doing nothing to itself.

There is a requirement for the standard containers that `iterator`is convertible to `const_iterator`. Deriving one from the other is one way of achieving this.

The `const_iterator` base class stores a pointer to a `Node` but the `iterator` does not, so passing the parameter on to the base class will initialize the `curr_` member that both base and derived can use.

> when accessing curr_ from iterator how would I refer to it? Would I just call curr_ or would I use this->curr_?

You can use `curr_` both in the base class and the derived as long as there is no question about whether it is a member variable or not. The fact that the name ends in an underscore is a common convention for member variable names.

If there is any doubt about he scope, you can use `this->member` to make it obvious that you refer to a member of the class.

Using `this->` when it really isn't needed is deemed extra confusing by some people (like me) so should probably be saved for cases where there is a *real* need to disambiguate a name.