# Defect report 1207

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I don't understand the reason for [this defect report 1207](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1207), more specifically in reference to the following sentence (emphasis is mine):

> Because the transformation of a member name into a class member access
>   expression (9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static] paragraph 3) only occurs
>   inside the body of a non-static member function, **the type of v in the
>   trailing-return-type is non-const** but is const in the return
>   expression, resulting in a type mismatch between the return expression
>   and the return type of the function.

**Edit**

That is, I don't understand why the type of v in the trailing return type is deduced to be non-const.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector v;
auto end() const -> decltype(v.begin()) { return v.begin(); }
```

`decltype(v.begin())`, in the trailing-return-type, is `iterator` - because `v` has the type `vector`, *seen from outside*.

But *inside the functions body*, the const-specifier of the member function `end()` is considered. 
The type of `v` is the type of `this->v` - which in turn depends on the const-ness of `this`.

`this`' pointee is `const` (because of the afore-mentioned const-specifier), thus the type of `this` inside the member function is `block const*`.

Therefore the type of `this->v` inside the member function is `vector const` (because of the const access-path), and `v.begin()` - which is actually `(this->v).begin()` - calls the `const`-overload whose return type is `const_iterator`.
On the other hand, `v.begin()` in the trailing-return-type "calls" the non-const overload that returns `iterator`.

That type inconsistence is the problem.

Comment: `On the other hand, v.begin() in the trailing-return-type "calls" the non-const overload that returns iterator.` Ok, but why is the non-const overload selected in this case?

Comment: Because the object argument `v` (seen from the trailing-return-type) isn't const-qualified. Therefore overload resolution finds the non-const overload to be a better match. But seen from the traling-return-type, `v` **should** be const-qualified, since the member function is.

Comment: What you're saying is that the `const` in the member function declaration doesn't apply to the trailing return type. Could you provide a reference for this?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Reference is given in the defect report. It says "Because the transformation of a member name into a class member access expression (9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static] paragraph 3) only occurs inside the body of a non-static member function, the type of v in the trailing-return-type is non-const"

Comment: I have no problem with the type inconsistency. What I just don't understand is why the use of `v` in the trailing return type is deduced to be non-const.

Comment: After seeing [this question and the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844339/1042389) I finally understood what you said above. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's saying that, when the trailing-return-type is parsed, the member `v` is looked up to sufficiently make sense of `v.begin()` .. but the actual *access* to `v` in the context of having invoked `end()` is not considered, so neither is the fact that `end()` (and therefore its access to `v`) is `const`.

Comment: Your answer actually helped me grasp it a bit better, thanks.