# How can I fix this error `conversion from const_iterator to non-scalar type`?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

can someone explain what is the mention of this error:

> conversion from 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}' requested

given the following class:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

template<class T>
class Gen {
    vector<T> array;
public:
    explicit Gen(int size);
    template<class S>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Gen<S>& g);
};

template<class T>
Gen<T>::Gen(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this->array.push_back(T());
    }
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Gen<T>& g) {
    for (typename vector<T>::iterator it = g.array.begin(); it != g.array.end();
            it++) { // ****** error ********
        os << *it << " ";
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Gen<int> g(3);
    std::cout << g << std::endl;
}
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ iterator and const\_iterator problem for own container class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844339/c-iterator-and-const-iterator-problem-for-own-container-class)

Comment: @MohammadKanan I can't do it without defines new class of Iterator?

Comment: Use `typename vector<T>::const_iterator` instead, that should work.

Comment: It's dense, but read the error message carefully. It's complaining about converting `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` to `std::vector<int>::iterator`. That's a problem, because `iterator` allows you to assign to the thing it points at, but `const_iterator` does not. The container is const, so you can't modify its elements. With practice these error messages become easier to decipher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing in a `const Gen<T>` to `operator<<`. This means when you call `g.array.begin()` you are invoking the const overload of begin, which returns a [const_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin):

```
const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
```

and then you try to assign it to a `vector<T>::iterator`, which causes the compiler error. You can fix this like this:

```
auto it = g.array.begin()
```

which tells the compiler to deduce the correct type for `it`.

Comment: Can I convert `const_iterator` to `iterator` by some way?

Comment: No. why would you want to?

Comment: How about iterator to const_iterator? is it possible to do such conversion?