# Why does my templated function require a conversion from one iterator to the other?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, const-iterator

I am trying to implement a binary search tree container. At the moment I have to implement a find() function that is able to return an iterator or a constant iterator. I choose to overload the find function to accomodate both possibilities

```
MyIterator<treepair> find(const key& x)
{
    return tree_search<MyIterator<treepair>>(root,x);   
}
const_MyIterator<treepair> find(const key& x) const
{
    return tree_search<const_MyIterator<treepair>>(root,x); 
}
```

Then the function tree_search recursively finds the node that contains the wanted key by percurring the tree:

```
template<typename iterator>
iterator tree_search(Node<treepair>* x, const key& y) const
{
    if(x == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"element not found"<<std::endl;
        iterator x = end();//HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
        return x;
    }
    else if (y == x->value.first)
    {
        iterator i{x,tree_maximum()};
        std::cout<<"element found"<<std::endl;
        return i;
    }
    if(y < x->value.first) 
        return tree_search<iterator>(x->left,y);
    else return tree_search<iterator>(x->right,y);
}
```

Now the end() function is overloaded to give both a const_iterator and a regular iterator:

```
MyIterator<treepair> end(){
return MyIterator<treepair>{nullptr,tree_maximum()};
}

const_MyIterator<treepair> end() const{
return const_MyIterator<treepair>{nullptr,tree_maximum()};
}
```

however I receive this error

```
test_on_iterators.cc:508:12: error: conversion from ‘const_MyIterator<std::pair<int, int> >’ to non-scalar type ‘MyIterator<std::pair<int, int> >’ requested
      iterator x = end();
```

Is this error due to a requirement in the conversion between the types? Isn't the compiler supposed to choose the wanted end() function according to the iterator type it has to produce?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ iterator and const\_iterator problem for own container class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844339/c-iterator-and-const-iterator-problem-for-own-container-class)

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the compiler supposed to choose the wanted end() function according to the iterator type it has to produce?

No.

`tree_search()` is a `const` method.  That means its `this` pointer is pointing at a `const` object (even if the object `tree_search()` is called on is not really `const`).

As such, when `tree_search()` internally calls `end()`, it calls the overload that is callable on a `const` object.  That overload returns a `const_MyIterator`.  Then `tree_search()` tries to assign that `const_MyIterator` to a non-const `MyIterator`, which is where you get the error since there is no conversion defined from `const_MyIterator` to `MyIterator`.

You need to make `x` be a `const_MyIterator` to match what the `const` version of `end()` returns.

You should also make `tree_search()` return a `const_MyIterator` as well, instead of returning a non-const `iterator`.  If you want `tree_search()` to return a non-const `Iterator`, then don't declare it as a `const` method.